# Need help having site load faster

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a section of a new site... let's call it hero, that loads in under a second. The secondary content, which dynamically loads thumbnails of each post (there are 100's) takes up to a minute to load.

I'd like to have the prioritized content (hero content) load under a second, as is, but then, and only then, load secondary content - only after primary content (hero) is fully loaded.

I'm using a WP platform, custom hero section and Grid FX plugin to call the secondary content.

Any help in making this site load faster is greatly appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: Caching and batching are your friends. Find a way to cache the thumbnails after creation and batch load them. Oh, and try not to load 100s of posts right away; you're hammering your server for no reason. Look into infinite scroll options instead.

Comment: Caching will likely help a lot, but the fact that it takes a minute to load is a little concerning. Does Grid FX dynamically generate image thumbnails?  That's not a good idea, and it makes me suspect that the plugin uses TimThumb.  Trust me - do not use TimThumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't be surprised if there's already a plugin that handles this for you, but it sounds remarkably similar to an scenario I faced on a site and I ended up coming up with the following solution.

There's essentially two factors at work that make this slow: first, the server has a query for the hundreds of posts, and *then* the browser has to fetch all of these thumbnails. So there's two separate things you can optimise:

**Step 1: The query**
First - as @EdCottrell pointed out - you can batch load those images OR you can use AJAX to request more posts via `admin-ajax.php`; this will return a JSON object that you can then use to create a bunch of elements with data-attributes for the image URLs (which will then be used in step 2). The steps required to do this are pretty long and as we're covering two different topics here it's probably more concise to point you towards [this article](http://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) which covers it in great detail.  In a nutshell you'll be:

1. Use `wp_localize_script()` to pass the correct path to `admin-ajax.php` to your JS
2. In your JS detect when your hero element is loaded and THEN make the AJAX request for more posts: this is actually a call to a function...
3. ... which would first check if you have the relevant permissions.
4. Presuming you have permissions you would then that perform a query for the posts and their thumbnails and then returns it as an object
5. If successful the JS then processes the object, creating some elements (such as some <`div>`s) to load the images into.

**Step 2: Loading the images**
Rather than simply loading in all the images at once - which can be slow - you can load them when the element is *actually in view*. You can do this using the [unveil.js](https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil) plugin which is fairly lightweight. Assuming you added a data-attribute of `data-thumbnail-src` in step 1 it would look something like:

```
$('.post-preview').one('unveil', function() {
    var src = $(this).attr('data-thumbnail-src'); // Get the src from the data-attribute
    $(this).attr('src', src); // Adding the src causes the image to load
}
```

Be aware that the above leaves out a few issues for brevity, such as HTML validity (images require *something* as a src attribute) and dimensions for the images, but it should hopefully be a good starting point.

Comment: I missed this when you posted originally Dre. Accepted it now. Appreciate your thoughtful reply, this is a huge help!